# WF4 - Designer - Right Click - ArgumentException - "An item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, workflow-foundation-4, designer

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and getting an ArgumentException when I'm right clicking following a copy\cut and paste operation...

Is this a bug in the designer? What's the easiest way to identify what's wrong here?

Thx!

[image]

Comment: Can you provide repro steps?

Answer (score 1):

Good news there is now a hotfix for this...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2828841

Comment: Do I need to contact microsoft to download this hotfix? Really? Can find any download button at all....

Comment: Unfortunately yes you do. It requires you to open a ticket with Microsoft.